# Variable inside a variable being interpreted

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

So I have a long command that is an obfuscated script (Powerview) and what I want to do is include is write the command into another .psm1, however a variable inside the obfuscated script is being interpreted and thus translated when written to the new .psm1. What's really boggling my mind is I take this command and put it into it's own .psm1, it works fine.

So here's the command:

```
$p1="(nEw-oBjEct  SysTeM.iO.streamReAder( (nEw-oBjEct  Io.comPressIon.DefLaTesTREAM( [iO.meMORystReAm][sysTEm.COnveRT]::frOmbaSe64StRinG('BASE64STUFFHERE=='), [iO.cOmpressIOn.COmpResSiOnmOde]::DeCOMprESs )),[teXt.eNCOdInG]::ascii)).ReADtoeND( ) | &( $vErbOsEpReferENce.tOStrinG()[1,3]+'X'-jOIN'')"
```

What happens is $verbosereference.tostring gets translated to "SilentlyContinue.tostring" which is not correct.

So I guess the question is how do I prevent that variable from being interpreted? I've tried escaping with single quotes but that isn't working properly

Comment: Got it. Instead of a double quote at the start, I started with a single quote, then double single quoted the base64 command and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a double quote at the start, I started with a single quote, then double single quoted the base64 command and it worked